# Ember.js how to properly initialize localstorage-adapter? (hasMany with async: true is not persisted)

Tags: ember.js, local-storage

I'm using ember.js with localstorage-adaper.js.

My problem started with an already answered question: [EmberJS - record with hasMany relation fails to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705686/emberjs-record-with-hasmany-relation-fails-to-load)

So having the models:

```
 // Models
    App.List = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        items: DS.hasMany('item')
    });  

    App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string') ,
        list: DS.belongsTo('list')
    });
```

When the #/list/1 template got rendered the the items weren't shown on the page and an assertion failed was thrown in the console:

`Assertion failed: You looked up the 'items' relationship on 'App.List:ember236:1' but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (DS.attr({ async: true }))`

As specified, the solution is to make the hasMany async like this:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('item',{async:true})
});
```

It works great for that scenario!

Next:

I'm loading data from the server and push it into the store when the application first loads like this: (You can find the JSBin for the example here: http://jsbin.com/lejizo/1/)

```
var data = { //in real life this is fetched through an AJAX request

      'list': { id: '1', name: 'The List', items: ['1','2'] },
      'items': {
          '1': { id: '1', name: 'item 1', list: '1' },
          '2': { id: '2', name: 'item 2', list: '1' }
        }
      };
```

...

```
this.store.push('list', data.list).save();
this.store.pushMany('item', data.items).forEach(function (item) {
     item.save();
});
```

After setting the async:true option, I've noticed that the items ids are not persisted anymore into the localstorage. The JSON looks like this:

```
{"App.List":{"records":{"1":{"id":"1","name":"The List","items":[]}}},"App.Item":{"records":{}}}
```

Obviously the items are not shown since there is no reference to them.

I might think that I should find another way to populate the locastorage at first! How?
Or there is another workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `aync:true` on `hasMany` relationships beside the foreign keys not being persisted to the localstorae, also causes additional problems inside controllers. You get the Promise, not the actual object, so you always must use `list.get('items').then(/*code here*/)` (check out this question I've posted [Ember local-storage How to use hasMany with async: true in controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805703/ember-local-storage-how-to-use-hasmany-with-async-true-in-controllers)), which in some scenarios where you use it inside a loop might cause a stackoverflow.

Using localstorage, you'll allways have all the data on the client side. It really makes no sense to work with async:true. The problem is that ember expects an array of vanilla objects for the `list.items`, instead of just ids. This is described here [DS.FixtureAdapter loses fixture data with hasMany async attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043438/ds-fixtureadapter-loses-fixture-data-with-hasmany-async-attributes)

There is an easy workaround for getting rid of `async:true` in your `hasMany` relationships. Please note that you have all needed data in localstorage! Ember doesn't throw the: `"Assertion failed: You looked up the 'items' relationship on 'App.List:ember236:1' but some of the associated records were not loaded..."` error anymore if he sees the items inside the memory store.

SOLUTION:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
    beforeModel: function(transition){
        this.store.find('list');
        this.store.find('items');
    }
});
```

We override the `Ember.Route` object, so that in the `beforeModel` hook we call `store.find('object')`. What this does is forces Ember to load data from localstorage to the "in memory" store! You won't need the `async:true` anymore and no error will be thrown. Also, at first initialization the foreign keys will be persisted too!

You have to do this everytime (in the Route super class) because you'll never know on which route a refresh will occur. Also, for a store of ~10 models with up to 50 records, it runs in ~50-70ms. If this seems to much in your scenario, make sure you do this call only on the route you want and only for the models it needs.

Also, if you override `beforeModel` inside your routes, make sure you call

```
this._super(transition)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You defined your data wrong, try this:

```
var data = { //in real life this is fetched through an AJAX request

      'list': { id: '1', name: 'The List', items: [1,2] },
      'items': [
          { id: '1', name: 'item 1', list: '1' },
          { id: '2', name: 'item 2', list: '1' }
      }];
}
```

First you do not need a index 1,2,... in front of your items.
Second hasMany relationship should be return an array that is why items is wrap as an array.
So to fix your issue you either have to fix the data from the server, or write a serializer to massage the data.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are right! I made a mistake when copy-pasting and actualizing JSBin, but that was not the problem