# Ember local-storage How to use hasMany with async: true in controllers?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember.js with localstorage-adapter

Here is a JSbin with the issue: http://jsbin.com/lejizo/9/edit?html,console,output

Having these models:

```
/* Models */
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    // DOES NOT WORK:: items: DS.hasMany('item')
    items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true})
});  

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    list: DS.belongsTo('list')
    });
```

Ember data throws an error if you don't make the `hasMany` asynchronous. By the way, the data is in the `localstoarge`. I initialize it like this:

```
var FIXTURES = {
    'list': {
        records: {
            '1': { 
                id: '1', 
                name: 'The List', 
                items: ['1','2'] 
            },
            '2': { 
                id: '2', 
                name: 'The Second List', 
                items: ['1','3'] 
            }
        }
    },
    'item': {
        records: {
            '1': { 
                id: '1', 
                name: 'item 1', 
                list: '1' },
            '2': { 
                id: '2', 
                name: 'item 2', 
                list: '1' 
            },
            '3': { 
                id: '3', 
                name: 'item 3', 
                list: '1' 
            }
        }
    }
}

localStorage.setItem('DS.LSAdapter', JSON.stringify(FIXTURES));
```

Anyways, making `items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true})` make the application run smoothly.

The problem is that if I try to access the `items` from a Controller they are not an object, they are only a promise! This force us use the following approach:

```
list.get('items').then(function(items) { // must use then
    items.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item.get('id'));
    });
});
```

This seems awkward to me, to always watch out for the `hasMany` relationships and be careful how you use them, instead of just work with the related objects as for any other relationship..

Is this normal or am I missing something? 
Is there a workaround to not define them async: true, since all the data is already in the localstorage? 
Should we always use then in controllers for all related entities as a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems awkward to me, to always watch out for the hasMany relationships and be careful how you use them, instead of just work with the related objects as for any other relationship..

That would be awkward, which is why you don't have to do that. ;) In most cases, Ember will automatically watch for property updates and propagate them accordingly. What does that mean? That means that you shouldn't worry that the value is a promise; *use it as if it wasn't one*.

In short, Ember uses a special kind of promise to watch for property updates. So let's say you have the following template:

```
{{#each item in model.items}}
    {{item.name}}
{{/each}}
```

If `model.items` is an asynchronous `hasMany` relationship, Ember will still do the right thing. When the template first renders, there will be no data. *Your `each` loop will produce nothing.* But Ember is going to watch the `model.items` property for updates. When it has an update (like when the promise resolves), Ember will *run the template again*. This time, the data will be there and it will work exactly as you expect.

The same holds true for properties:

```
function() {
    return this.get('model.items').filter(function(item) {
        return !!item;
    });
}.property('model.items.@each')
```

This property will return an empty array the first time it runs. But when the promise resolves, Ember will run the property again and produce the result you want.

Behind the scenes of that there's a lot going on, but you generally don't need to worry about that until you get into some more complicated use cases. If you'd like to know more, I suggest checking out these resources:

1. [The RSVP Promise library](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/)
2. [Ember's guide on asynchrony](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/)
3. The [ObjectProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectProxy.html) and [ArrayProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) classes
4. The [PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html) class

EDIT: If you want to modify the relationship, for instance, add a new item, do something like this:

```
actions: {
    addPost: function(post) {
        this.get('model.posts').then(function(posts) {
            posts.addObject(post);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that they work great in templates. I didn't knew that .property() handles them too. Thanks! Still, I'm not convinced.. What if in a controller action I must do something with model.idems? It seems that model.get('items') returns a promise, not an array! Please check the exmaple: http://jsbin.com/lejizo/9/edit?html,console,output

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example on how most people modify `hasMany` relationships. You may struggle at first with the asynchrony, but it'll come to you. Just remember one **very** important thing: asynchronous does not mean slow.